# Find vulnerabilities in ARM IoT device

Tags: ida, arm, vulnerability-analysis, ida-plugin

I have an ARM IoT device with a web interface, and I have the binary of this device open in Ida Pro.

I looking for vulnerabilities in the webserver binary that can be exploited to run commands or bypass authentication.

There is the manual way, looking for unsafe functions in the binary that are susceptible to buffer overflows, or looking in the webserver to find input that is passed to `exec` or other input that can download files from the system.

I know this is the manual and slow way.

Is there any tool or maybe Ida Pro plugin that helps to find a vulnerabilities in binaries/in web applications?

Comment: Not free ($$$) https://www.refirmlabs.com/centrifuge-platform/

Comment: Open Source: [FACT - The Firmware Analysis and Comparison Tool](https://fkie-cad.github.io/FACT_core/)

Comment: @0xec do you work with those tools? Do you recommend on them?? I saw those tool emulate first you device by firmware,do they know to find vulnerable without emulate the device?

Comment: Nope. Personally I didn't use those tools. I think they identify possible vulnerabilities by static analysis.

Comment: You could always find or write scripts to assist with these tasks.